# Why always it is updating for both the genders?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `up40`(in raise int, in gender char(1))
    begin
    if(gender = 'M') then
      update teste set wage = wage + raise where gender = 'M';
    end if;
    if(gender = 'F') then
      update teste set wage = wage + raise where gender = 'F';
    end if;
    end;
```

Comment: I think you don't need `IF` condition here. `WHERE` is enough.

Comment: `=` this one is the comparison operator in `MySQL` @Kool-Mind

Comment: It's an odd query- especially as a procedure

Answer (score 1):

You can give this a try:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `up40` (
    IN raise INT,
    IN genderParam CHAR (1)
)
BEGIN
    UPDATE teste SET wage = wage + raise
    WHERE gender = genderParam;

END;
```

---

Try to use different names for variables so that you can differentiate the column names and variables.

And also you don't need those if conditions. Just a simple update statement with where clause should suffice.